# Generic List/Dictionary based on Property/Parameter

Tags: c#, generics, generic-programming

For starters, I have implemented a workaround to this question based on having multiple private variables store information, and get/set on the affected object.

The scope of this questions is for learning/reference.

Scenario:
I have an interface that manages multiple objects (2 in this example).

```
interface Imoon
??? SomePropertyName {get;set;}

class Foo : Imoon
public TypeA SomePropertyName {get;set;}
public enumMyType TypeStorage {get;set}

class Bar : Imoon
public TypeB SomePropertyName {get;set;}
public enumMyType TypeStorage {get;set;}
```

The goal is to be able to reference a list/dictionary/array of objects that may change in type (similiar to a generic). The types don't impact the logic, they are partitioned into separate handlers and managed there.

- Once declared, the type of the object does not change.
- The Type is the same for all elements within the Enumerable, however may change between different objects.

Example declarations:

```
Dictionary<string,TypeA> myDictionary;
Dictionary<string,TypeB> myDictionary;
```

or as a list:

class Foo

```
List<TypeA> myValues
List<string> myKeys
```

class Bar

```
List<TypeB> myValues
List<string> myKeys
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how to implement this, or suggestions for improvement please let me know :)

Comment: @Kevin Ran into issues with accessing the "SomePropertyName" as an array/list/dictionary or the generic types. 
For example: SomePropertyName.Count, to access the property i will have to supply the type for each call, I used a wrapper to direct the call to the specified type.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: what are you trying to do describe your problem, not your intended solution, it seems like you just need to change your architecture

Comment: @johnny5 Sure thing. 
I would like be able to manage two different object types (not custom objects) with the same properties (which is why i'm thinking an interface with generics).

The objects are currently stored using a key that relates to the source location of the object (Dictionary Key), and the object of each type (TypeA and TypeB) is stored in the paired value (Dictionary Value).
KeyValuePair = < String SourceLocation, Object>

Previously this was stored as 4 separate dictionaries, reduced to 2, by using a property for an unrelated attribute, looking to reduce to 1 dictionary.

Comment: Its still unclear what you're trying to do, but what I'm gettings TypeA and TypeB are both Keys?  Then they should both inherit from an interface IKey, and you should just have a dictionary of IKey's

Comment: Ok, let me try a different way. 
Within a collection of files, i have two file types. These 2 files types are handled by separate handlers, however they are linked in regards to the rest of the functionality. They are moved and processed as a pair, for every file of typeb, there is a matching file of typeA.

Each of these types have  some properties that are the same, and some that are different. 

Having a parent object, to store the identical properties, and two sub objects would resolve this issue. However, i can't create an interface to handle the two, that only differ by filetype.

Comment: hmm? sounds like you need a generic interface, or better yet, just use an enum to seperate the file types and use an interface

Comment: I'll attempt this, and update with the result.

Comment: @johnny5 This resolved my issue. I'll post the example code below incase someone else runs into this issue.

Comment: Glad, it works!

Comment: I can't give you any points/Karma in a comment, But thank you!

Comment: Seeds it’s okay you did all the work I just gave you the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Archiving, I was able to reach the desired result by using a Generic interface as Recommended by johnny5 above.
I've included a example of the solution, and how to implement it with a given type (TypeA), and it could be done on TypeB aswell.

```
public interface ICollection<T>
{
    Dictionary<string,T> TypeDictionary { get; set; }
    void AddToDictionary(Dictionary<string,T> Addition
    int FileCount { get; }
}

public class TypeACollection : ICollection<TypeA>
{
    private Dictionary<string,TypeA> myTypeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, TypeA>();
    public void AddToDictionary(Dictionary<string, TypeA> Addition)
    {
        foreach (var keyValuePair in Addition)
        {
            TypeDictionary[keyValuePair.Key] = keyValuePair.Value;
        }
    }
    public Dictionary<string, TypeA> GetTypeDictionary()
    {
        return TypeDictionary;
    }

    private void ClearDictionary()
    {
        TypeDictionary.Clear();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, TypeA> TypeDictionary { 
         get {   return myTypeDictionary; } 
         set {   myTypeDictionary = value; } 
    }

    public int FileCount {get { return TypeDictionary.Keys.Count; }}
}
public class TypeA { }
public class TypeB { }
```